# jQuery image gallery

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I am not sure if this will be right place to ask the question, but I have spent las 2 hours on Google trying to find something.

Im looking for image gallery/sideshow that will look like the one on dell web site.

www.dell.com

Can anyone direct me to one please?

I would really appreciate.

Thanks

Dom

Comment: If you refer to the one on the front page that is a flash gallery thus the jquery tag is quite misleading on your question. But there are literally tons of jQuery slideshow/imagegallery plugins out there. But nobody can do the styling for you. Do adapt the CSS to look the way you want is left up to you

Comment: Look at this gallery, that i wrote few days ago. It very similar to what google use: https://github.com/creotiv/jquery-photowall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one seems to be doing what you are looking for:
**Demo:** http://tugbucket.net/tests/gallery/index.html
**Site:** http://tugbucket.net/jquery/jquery-fading-and-sliding-image-gallery/
With a little styling you can make an exact match.

The one on Dell.com is done in flash/flex so you could also google for flash image gallery. I would however go for the jquery gallery approach because I always assume that
*the amount of users using javascript **>** the amount of users using flash*

For a list of other jquery galleries, looky here:
http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/06/03/15-great-jquery-images-gallery-plugins-to-showcase-your-work/
http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/03/five-jquery-galleries-and-slideshows/
http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a paid version slider. Really sexy:

http://codecanyon.net/item/sexy-slider/87148